# Prove $\sqrt{x}$ is Hölder 1/2

Tags: analysis, holder-spaces

First of all I want to mention that this is about an assignment I was given at school. I don't need the straight answer as much as a few hints to get started.

To give you a context, at the moment we're beginning to study integrals.

The question I'm stuck at is to verify :

Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,+\infty[$. The exercise then suggest that this can be accomplished by proving $f$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\frac12$.

So I know if $f$ is Hölder 1/2 then we must have :

$$ \exists C \in \mathbb{R}, \forall (x,y) \in [0,+\infty[^2 : \left( |f(x)-f(y)| \le C.|x-y|^{1\over 2}\right)$$

Applied to $\sqrt{x}$ it gives :

$$ \exists C \in \mathbb{R}, \forall (x,y) \in [0,+\infty[^2 : \left( |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}| \le C.|x-y|^{1\over 2}\right)$$

Which is

$$ \exists C \in \mathbb{R}, \forall (x,y) \in [0,+\infty[^2 : \left( {|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\over |x-y|^{1\over 2}} \le C\right)$$

This is where I'm stuck. I think I'm missing some kind of comparison theorem relative to the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$

Please provide me with hints, thanks.

Comment: Intuitively, where in the domain of $\hspace{.04 in}f$ should your ratio be largest? ​ Show that it is in fact at least as large there as everywhere else. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The last reformulation is useless but starting from the previous to last, you want to compare $$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt{|x-y|}$$ hence it suffices 1. to compare their squares, 2. to assume that $x>y$ by symmetry, 3. to assume that $y=1$ (dividing everything by $\sqrt{y}$). Thus, you want to compare $$(\sqrt{x}-1)^2=x+1-2\sqrt{x}\quad\text{and}\quad x-1$$ for $x>1$. Can you continue?

Comment: Thanks Did. I'm trying to do the comparaison, I'm here :
$$ |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|^2 = (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 = x - 2.\sqrt{x}.\sqrt{y} + y  $$ 
and 
$$\sqrt{|x-y|}^2 = |x-y| = \sqrt{(x-y)^2} = \sqrt{x^2 - 2.x.y + y^2}$$
But I don't really see how to compare the two.

Comment: Since you assumed that $x>y$, you want to determine the sign of $$(x-y)-(x-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}+y)$$ which is also $$2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}-2y=2\sqrt{y}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})$$ whose sign is ... hence you are done, right? (Unrelated: Please use @, I saw your comment only by chance.)

Answer (score 4):

We have: $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=\dfrac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}=\sqrt{|x-y|}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{|x-y|}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}\leq 1\cdot |x-y|^{\frac{1}{2}}$, since $\sqrt{|x-y|} \le \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is clearly true.

Comment: Quote: "I don't need the straight answer as much as a few hints to get started." For once we have a user who seems interested in *understanding* rather than in getting ASAP an answer ready to be handed back to their TA, so...

Comment: You can post fast answers f they answer the question. Here, technically, you do not answer the question since the question does not ask for what you provide.