# Bounded and Continuous but not Holder

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

This is a follow-up question to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016697/example-of-a-continuous-and-a-bounded-function-which-is-not-lipschitz-continuous).  Does there exist an example of a bounded and continuous *but not necessarily uniformly continuous* function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which is *not* H\"{o}lder continuous?

Comment: Thanks, but uniform continuity is not continuity on non-compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The given example ($f(x) = 1/\log(z)$ for $0 < x \le 1/2$ is not Hölder continuous at $x=0$. You can easily extend it to all of $\Bbb R$, while preserving the non-Hölder continuity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on $[0,1]$ the  function  $\sqrt x$ is bounded and continuous but not Lipschitz.

Suppose, if possible, $|\sqrt x -\sqrt y| \leq C|x-y|$. Then $|\frac {x-y} {\sqrt x  +\sqrt y}| \leq C|x-y|$ which gives $1 \leq C (\sqrt x  +\sqrt y)$ and we get a contradiction by letting $x$ and $y$ tend to $0$.

A bounded continuous function which is not Holder continuous of any order is given by $f(x)=\frac 1 {\ln x}$ for $0<x\leq \frac  1 2$ and $0$ for $x=0$. For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: If you wish you can  extend it to the whole line by making  it $o$ for $x <0$ and $1$ for $x >1$.

Comment: You have shown that $f$ is not Lipschitz, but not that it is not Hölder continuous. The square root function *is* Hölder: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950257/prove-sqrtx-is-hölder-1-2.

Comment: True, thanks Martin.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @AIM_BLB I have edited my answer.

Comment: That example was already given here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/144292/42969. As I pointed out, the question is a *duplicate* and should be closed as such.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Kavi.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I honestly don't understand it. I pointed out that the *identical answer* has been given in another Q&A. The proper action would be to cast a “close as duplicate” vote on the question (and delete the wrong answer). Instead you repeat the other answer here.